# TensorFlow Error when Adding F1Score Metric: "ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32"

Tags: tensorflow, valueerror

I am experiencing an issue with TensorFlow while training a VGG16-based model. The model compiles successfully, but I encounter a ValueError during training when I include the F1Score metric. Precision and Recall work fine. The error is:

**ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>**

I suspect the error might be due to a datatype mismatch between **y_pred** and **y_true**. The F1Score metric seems to expect both to have the same datatype, but I'm not explicitly handling these tensors, as TensorFlow is supposed to manage them automatically. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
def compile_model(self):
    self.model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=[
            "accuracy",
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
            tf.keras.metrics.F1Score(), # the error appears when I add this line
        ],
    )

def train_model(self):
    train_ds = load_dataset(self.train_ds_path)
    val_ds = load_dataset(self.val_ds_path)

    # Train the model
    self.model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=self.epochs,
        callbacks=self.callbacks,
        verbose=1,
    )

def load_dataset(dataset_dir, batch_size=32, img_height=224, img_width=224):
    ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        dataset_dir, seed=123, image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size
    )

    def preprocess_data(image, label):
        image = preprocess_input(image)
        return image, label

    ds = ds.map(preprocess_data)

    return ds
```

The error appears when I call the **self.model.fit function**.

Tensorflow version: **2.15.0**

Thank you!

Comment: Currently, `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()` returns the labels as `int`s. You can change that with the `label_mode` parameter, set it to `label_mode='binary'`, for float32 labels working with `binary_crossentropy`. [Link to the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory).